# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptography, ethereum, js-ethereum-cryptography

I am trying to generate random cryptographic keys, but when I try to run my app, it results to this error in my browser console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')`.

Here is my code:

```
import secp from "ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1";
import { keccak256 } from "ethereum-cryptography/keccak";
import { toHex } from "ethereum-cryptography/utils";

const privateKey = secp.utils.randomPrivateKey();
console.log('Private key:', toHex(privateKey));

const publicKey = secp.getPublicKey(privateKey);
console.log('Public key:', toHex(publicKey));

const address = (keccak256(publicKey.slice(1)).slice(-20));
console.log('Ethereum public key:', toHex(address));

function GenerateKey() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Private key: {privateKey}</p>
            <p>Public key: {publicKey}</p>
            <p>Address: {address}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GenerateKey;
```

Please how can I fix this?

Comment: try to install `ethereum-cryptography` again. The problem seems to be related to importing `toHex` from `ethereum-cryptography/utils`.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling but it still shows the same error. Please i've updated my question with image of the error, can you please look through.

Comment: the error is on line 5. try to CTRL + click on `randomPrivateKey` of `secp.utils`. I mean, check if there is a method called `randomPrivateKey` inside `secp.utils`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use imports like this:

```
import {
  getPublicKey,
  utils,
} from 'ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1'
```

And then generate your keys:

```
const privateKey = utils.randomPrivateKey()

const publicKey = getPublicKey(privateKey)
```

You get an error because `ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1` path doesn't have a default export.

Another approach is to use `* as` construction:

```
import * as secp from 'ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1'

const privateKey = secp.utils.randomPrivateKey()

const publicKey = secp.getPublicKey(privateKey)
```

Comment: Yeah the second approach worked for me, thanks for the answer
I'll be glad if you could recommend materials that have helped you in your react journey

Comment: My pleasure!
If you aren't aware React has a new comprehensive documentation [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/). It's truly great. You can find there everything you need for a good start in React! Best regards ✋

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the *secp* as *secp256k1* as shown below:

Change line 1 to:

```
import { secp256k1 } from 'ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1';
```

Change line 5 to:

```
const privateKey = secp256k1.utils.randomPrivateKey();
```

Change line 8 to:

```
const publicKey = secp256k1.getPublicKey(privateKey);
```

This is because of the updates that were made on the secp256k1 module. Before, it was using the [noble-secp256k1 1.7](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-secp256k1) and now it is using the safer [noble-curve](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves#implementations). Please refer to the [upgrading section from curves README](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves#upgrading).

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing
import secp from "ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1";

by
const { secp256k1 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1.js");

and instead of
secp.utils ... use secp256k1.utils

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).